# htaccess Permanent redirect from extension to slug

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with a million plus pages indexed in Google as:

```
/item.php?i=9
```

How can I permanently redirect these so they go to:

```
/items/9/
```

What I have so far is doing the opposite of what I want to happen.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /item.php?i=$1 [R=301]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+item\.php\?i=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /items/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^items/([0-9]+)/?$ /item.php?i=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is still doing the opposite of what I want, it redirects /9 to item.php?i=9.

Comment: No it doesn't. Test in a different browser.

Comment: Did you this in a new browser?

Comment: I did, it is still doing what I mentioned above.

Comment: See update and make sure to enter: `http://domain.com/item.php?i=9` in a new browser to test